# simplexml_load_file(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity

Tags: php

It was working fine on PHP 5.3

```
$objXmlFile = simplexml_load_file( 'test.xml' );
$arrresElements = $objXmlFile->xpath( '/id' );
```

But After updating from PHP 5.3 to 5.4 its giving following error:

> simplexml_load_file(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity

Is there anything changed in 5.4

Comment: Is that `test.xml` on the very same directory ?

Comment: No idea if this is related but check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14344849/php-simplexml-load-file-fails

Comment: @shankar..Yes its in same directory...And this all was working fine on PHP 5.3 but its not working with 5.4

Comment: @user3572246, Can you post that XML here ? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, i cant post..:(..Its confidential..Just tell me is anything wrong with version up-gradation??

Comment: Try loading a sample xml file from any XML tutorial (like W3C). That will, at the very least, negate the possibility that the issue lies with your XML file.